# Find Facebook Photos my Page is tagged in

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tags

I've built a nice Photo Gallery on a website using Photo Albums from a Facebook business Page.

Pulling the photo albums and content from Facebook is working fine, but I want to add to it a "Customers Photos" feature by allowing customers to tag the page in their own photos.

To do this, I need to merge tagged photos with albums, but I can''t figure out how to get them.

```
http://graph.facebook.com/553788181316876/photos?fields=picture
```

Should do it as I understand, providing we have the correct access token.

But, I have been messing with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

and can't get anything to come out except for the profile picture.

There is currently only one photo that this page has been tagged in, it is a photo on my own personal profile, and I have definitely set the privacy on that to `public`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in the end

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/?
fields=albums.fields(name,photos.fields(picture),updated_time,cover_photo),
tagged.fields(picture,updated_time,name)&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

This gives me two sets of data, photo albums and their content, and also all tagged images.